# Run protractor selenium and python unit test one after other

Tags: python, selenium, protractor, python-unittest

I have protractor selenium tests and another tests using python unit test.
Both are independent. I would like to tun one protractor tests, if it pass then run one python test and if this gets pass then again run protractor test.

How can we achieve this? any thoughts?

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: @Davesexcel I have not tried anything yet, figuring out how could it be done.

Comment: Have you figured out how to run python and protractor simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a simple shell loop.  I don't know what system you're on, so I'll just outline the process.

```
return_code = 0
while return_code == 0
    return_code = run_one_selenium_test
    if return_code == 0
        return_code = run_one_unittest
    endif
endwhile
```

Does this address the problem you're having?

Do you need help to step through a list of tests?

Comment: I have protractor selenium framework which I am running using grunt and python unittest. I need to run 10 selenium and 10 python tests. What do you mean by "run_one_selenium_test", I run my protractor suite using grunt "task".

Comment: Right.  How do you run a single selenium test?  Put that command in place of _run_one_selenium_test_.  Do likewise with _run_one_unittest_.

You may have to iterate through lists of tests.  Do you know how to do that?  Also, what happens if there are more tests in one list than in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible
1. Create a visual studio solution
2. In one add python solution
3. In another add selenium solution
4. Call from a common solution on top

I did this with protractor + python combined and it worked like mint.